# Dirac Delta in two dimensions

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I would like to compute the following two dimensional integral:
$$\iint  f(\vec{x})\delta(|\vec{x}| -v)d^2\vec{x},$$
$$f(\vec{v})=\Bigg(\frac{m}{2\pi k_BT}\Bigg)^{3/2}\exp{\Big(\frac{-mv^2}{2k_BT}\Big)},$$
where $f$ is a smooth function.
I absolutely don't know how to deal with such integrals, and I don't have any knowledge (expect the defintion) of the Dirac Delta function in higher dimensions.

Comment: It's still true that $\int f(x)\textrm{d}\delta_v=f(v)$, regardless of dimension.

Comment: But I mean, that would, to me at least, be the definition of the Dirac Delta.

Comment: What the person who gave you this task wants you to do is integrate in polar coordinates. There, the Dirac delta as you write it acts exactly as in one dimension. Also be careful with your notation. $v$ in your first equation is a scalar, in your second it’s a vector.

Comment: @Benjamin Can you write a detailed answer for me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the calculation you asked for, let me point out the Dirac delta is **not** a function and the symbol $ \int f(x)\delta(x)d x $ is not to be taken literally. Digging into details on this side, however, would lead to a lengthy answer. Therefore, I will stick to the physics notation, which you also use in the question.

Now lets look at your integral and start by noting, that the term $\delta(|\vec x|-v)$ is actually a one-dimensional Dirac delta. The main task therefore is, to extract its one-dimensional character. This is done, by integrating in spherical coordinates.

We work under the following two assumptions: integration is over $\mathbb R^d$ and $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and rotation invariant. I will abuse notatino and write $f(|\vec r|)=f(\vec r)$ from now on. Then, integration in spherical coordinates yields
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^d} f(\vec r)\delta(|\vec r|-v)d\vec r &= \int_{\mathbb R^+} dr r^{d-1} \int_{S^{d-1}}dA f(r)\delta(r-v)\\
&=v^{d-1}f(v)\int_{S^{d-1}}dA\\
&= v^{d-1}f(v)A(S^{d-1}),
\end{align*}
where $A(S^{d-1})$ denotes the area of the $(d-1)$-dimensional unit sphere.

**Edit adding the not rotation invariant case:** You can also drop the assumption, that $f$ is rotation invariant. Then, a similar calculation as above yields
$$ \int_{\mathbb R^d} f(\vec r)\delta(|\vec r|-v)d\vec r = v^{d-1}\int_{S^{d-1}}f(v\vec n_A)dA, $$
where $\vec n_A$ denotes the normal vector on the unit sphere. So the volume integral reduces to a surface integral on the unit sphere by the Dirac delta.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\iint
\pars{m \over 2\pi\,\mrm{k_{B}}T}^{3/2}
\exp{\pars{-\,{m\verts{\vec{x}}^{2} \over 2\mrm{k_{B}}T}}}
\delta\pars{\verts{\vec{x}} - v}\dd^{2}\vec{x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{m \over 2\pi\,\mrm{k_{B}}T}^{3/2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp{\pars{-\,{m\rho^{2} \over 2\mrm{k_{B}}T}}}
\delta\pars{\rho - v}\rho\,\dd\rho\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\pars{m \over 2\pi\,\mrm{k_{B}}T}^{3/2}
\braces{2\pi v\
\exp{\pars{-\,{mv^{2} \over 2\mrm{k_{B}}T}}}\bracks{v > 0}}} \\ &
\end{align}